# executing (refreshing) a php file that is included on some page

Tags: php, forms, include

Suppose if I have a PHP file test.php which includes 2 other

```
<?php
include 'input.php';

include 'output.php';
?>
```

Input.php is a form with 1 button on it. Currently when clicking on that button I am executing the whole test.php file and output.php gives me the results I want.
I am using something similar to this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
.
.
.
</form>
```

But I don't want whole test.php to be executed, because that way I reset all input values in input.php.Can I execute just the output.php but display it on test.php?

Comment: You will have to make an ajax call to do that

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the AJAX and then refresh only the snippets you want to refresh.

But you would have to have some handler which will solve the form submit and then will return the result.

AJAX example (using jQuery):

add id to the form

```
<form action="test.php" id="form" method="POST">


$('#form').onsubmit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  data = $(this).serialize()
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "handler.php",
    data: { data: data }
  })
  .done(function( data) {
    //refresh data snippet
  });
)};
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/